# How to delete repositories in the form of URL in Debian terminal

Tags: repository

How to delete some of these sources, as shown in picture, via terminal? Help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are *usually* stored in /etc/apt/sources.list or /etc/apt/sources.list.d

I'd recommend backing up sources.list and sources.list.d, then simply editing out the lines you don't want, or deleting the files with the entries you don't need in sources.list.d.

Run apt update and the sources you removed will be gone.